# Prove that $\sin^4n/\sqrt n$ is monotonically decreasing

Tags: monotone-functions

How can we prove that this function

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin^4x}{\sqrt x}$$

is monotonically decreasing? I tried to use usual method using derivative, but it do not give us an answer.

Comment: It is not monotonically decreasing.

Comment: it must be $$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)^4 }{\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: see here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28x%29%5E4%2Fsqrt%28x%29+for+x%3D0+to+10 the given function isn't monoton

Comment: Try $g(x)=f(x^2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way could be to plot it using a software like R. The function isn't monotonically decreasing.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

We have 
$$f(x) = \dfrac{\sin^4 x}{\sqrt{x}} \geq 0$$
and
$$f(\pi) = 0$$
If it were decreasing, we would have $f(x) = 0$ for every $x \geq \pi$, which is clearly not the case.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = \frac{\sin^4{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$ is not monotonic decreasing. To see this, evaluate the derivative at $1$.